# A way to have multiple price points in an array and then have a for loop go over the array and create a horizontal line at each price point

Tags: arrays, pine-script, pine-editor

I made an array containing all of the price points that i  had, and then I ran a for loop after that with a statement to  create a horizontal line with each of the price points. This is my first night learning pine editor, i have no clue how to find/use their terminal or where the error messages pop out.

```
float[] priceList = array.from(138.73, 140.47, 139.59, 141.25, 138.9)
for i = 0 to array.size(priceList) - 1
    hline([i], title = "Price Line", color = color.red, linestyle = hline.style_solid, linewidth = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code won't compile, since `hline` function requires input form type. Use the newer, more flexible, `line` function:

```
float[] priceList = array.from(138.73, 140.47, 139.59, 141.25, 138.9)

for i = 0 to array.size(priceList) - 1
    line.new(0, array.get(priceList, i), bar_index, array.get(priceList, i), extend = extend.both, color = color.red)
```

Some side notes -

1. If you want to loop through an array, you can use `for...in` loop.
2. Pine script runs on each bar, and currently we are creating all those lines on each bar without deleting them. You can specify the script to run only once on the very last bar to optimize this.

```
float[] priceList = array.from(138.73, 140.47, 139.59, 141.25, 138.9)

if barstate.islast
    for [index, price] in priceList
        line.new(0, array.get(priceList, index), bar_index, array.get(priceList, index), extend = extend.both, color = color.red)
```

**EDIT:**

If you do want to create new lines and delete them later using an array, you can use another `array` which will be an array of lines, and then delete the lines if a condition is met:

```
float[] priceList = array.from(open, high, low, close)

line[] lineList = array.new_line(array.size(priceList))
                                
if yourCondition
    for [index, line] in lineList
        line.delete(array.get(lineList, index))
        newPrice = array.get(priceList, index)
        array.set(lineList, index, line.new(0, newPrice, bar_index, newPrice, extend = extend.both))
```

Comment: Since this is technically an indicator and I am using it as a way to add levels, after the levels are added is there a way to delete a single horizontal line, like you would after you just normally place one or not? after I got all of my horizontal lines added I tried to delete 1 line and it deleted every single one.

Comment: Since this is technically an indicator and I am using it as a way to add levels, after the levels are added is there a way to delete a single horizontal line, like you would after you just normally place one or not? after I got all of my horizontal lines added I tried to delete 1 line and it deleted every single one.

Comment: See my edit and check if it works

Comment: the code doesn't work I am not getting a compile error but instead a study error, it says "Bar index value of the 'x1' argument (0.000000) in 'line.new()' is too far from the current bar index. Try using 'time' instead

Comment: Since we are using `extend.both`, you can use `bar_index - 1` as an argument instead of `0`. Change the last line to `array.set(lineList, index, line.new(bar_index - 1, newPrice, bar_index, newPrice, extend = extend.both))`